# aiocron.crontab() срабатывает 2 раза (Python aiocron)

Tags: python, mysql, aiogram, asyncio, cron

```
@aiocron.crontab("25 15 * * *")
async def notifications():

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE notifications = 1""")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        
        print(rows)
        
    capit = post.cap('c')
    vol = post.cap('v')
    domin = post.cap('d')
    fear_ind = post.first_inf('f')
    spx_sv = post.spx_price()
    dow_j = post.dow()
    nasq  = post.nasq()
    bitcoin  = post.btc_price()
    usd_rub = post.usd_price()
    eur_rub = post.eur_price()
    gold_pr = post.gold_price()
    oil_pr = post.gold_price()
    spx_pr = post.spx_price()
    #dxy_pr = post.dxy_price()

    for row in rows:
        await bot.send_photo(row[0], open('photo/ind_100_total_7.jpg', 'rb'), f"{'<b>'}Общая сводка по рынку:{'</b>'} {datetime.now().date()}\n\n{'<u>'}{'<i>'}Сведения по рынку:{'</i>'}{'</u>'}\n\nРыночная капитализация: {capit}\nОбъем за 24ч: {vol}\nДоминирование BTC: {domin}\nИндекс страха и жадности - {fear_ind}\n\n{'<u>'}{'<i>'}Американские индексы:{'</i>'}{'</u>'}\n\nS&P 500: {spx_sv}\nDow Jones: {dow_j}\nNasdaq 100: {nasq}\n\n{'<u>'}{'<i>'}Ключевые события:{'</i>'}{'</u>'}\n\n{svodka_9_sob}\n\nОсновные курсы:\nBitcoin - {bitcoin}\nUSD/RUB - {usd_rub}\nEUR/RUB - {eur_rub}\nGold - {gold_pr}\nOil brent - {oil_pr}\nS&P 500 - {spx_pr}", parse_mode='HTML')
```

Данная функция должна брать id телеграмм пользователей и с помощью Aiogram делать рассылку в 9 утра. Проблема в том, что функция срабатывает дважды, пользователю приходит 2 одинаковых сообщения.

Много чего перепробовал, так и не смог выяснить в чем проблема, может кто-то подскажет другой способ делать рассылку в определенное время

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте зайти в редис (команда `redis-cli`), затем наберите `flushall` и после этого снова запустите бот. 
Мне это помогло.